# Which OpenCV4Android class does the field/constant CV_FILLED belongs to?

Tags: android, opencv, contour

What OpenCV4Android class does the field `CV_FILLED` belong to? I couldn't find out from my Google search.

It is used as the value of the 5th argument to the [`Imgproc.drawContours()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#drawcontours) method. From the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#drawcontours):

> **thickness** – Thickness of lines the contours are drawn with. If it is negative (*for example, thickness=CV_FILLED* ), the contour interiors are drawn.

I need to use it but in Android/Java, I can't use it just like that, I need to use the name of the class it belongs to with the dot operator, something like `theClass.CV_FILLED`. If I try to use just `CV_FILLED`, compiler complains,
"CV_FILLED cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: You can use `-1`, or any other negative value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drawContour example:

```
Imgproc.drawContours(drawOn, handContours, idx, new Scalar(180, 10, 100, 255), Core.BORDER_DEFAULT, Core.LINE_8, new Mat(), 25, new Point(0, 0));
```

So you should use Core.FILLED for example.